# Don't understand how Scala closure works

Tags: scala, functional-programming, closures

What is wrong here ?
I create a function, closureDemo, that takes another function which doesnot accept any params and doesnot return anything.
When I call closureDemo, I pass a function that matches this criteria.
But the I dont get the expected output. I expect the following output:-

```
This is a demo application
this is a demo for closure
```

But only the first line gets printed.
Can someone please explain what is going on here

```
object ScalaApp {

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("This is a demo application")
    closureDemo {
      () => println("this is a demo for closure")
    }
  }


  def closureDemo(op: => Unit) = {
    op
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Amar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `op` parameter `closureDemo` is call-by-name, which means it will not be evaluated until you call it. This is fine, since you are calling it, *but*, in `main` you are passing `() => println(...)` which is a function with zero parameters. Within the body of `closureDemo`, the call to `op` returns a function, but does not invoke the function.

If you want `closureDemo` to remain call-by-name, you shouldn't pass it a function, like so:

```
closureDemo(println("this is a demo for closure"))
```

If you only want to pass `closureDemo` functions with zero parameters you want to later invoke, its signature should reflect that:

```
def closureDemo(op: () => Unit) = {
  op()
}
```

Comment: It should also be noted that there aren't really any closures being used here, just functions that don't refer to any outside variables.

Comment: I have accepted this as an answer. Thank you for your explanation

Comment: I thought I was using closures, but I guess I will reach ther eventually

Answer (score 2):

This is because closureDemo demo takes a by-name parameter. 
and in your closureDemo call in the main function you are just creating/defining a parameterless function not calling it. so by forcing the evaluation of the newly created function you get the intended result

```
closureDemo {
   (() => println("this is a demo for closure")).apply()
 }
```

or alternatively you can simply call since the input to your closureDemo is not a function but a by-name parameter (code-block)

```
closureDemo(println("this is a demo for closure"))
```

Comment: This is in line with the accepted answer. Thank you for helping me out.